# Wcf service access and routing through IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I have a wcf self-hosted service running as windows service, serving multiple win/web clients in the local network. Service itself has multiple contracts (tcp & named pipes), one of which should be made available through IIS (any form of http binding) so it can be accessed from outside, like by simply accessing www.mypublicdomain.com/public-contract.svc

Current topology:

- Server app - wcf windows service
- Client app1 - win forms app - contacts server app via tcp/ip
- Client app2 - mvc web app (available both internally and via internet though public domain) - contacts server app via named pipes (same machine)

  - this app is hosted on iis7 and new public wcf contract should be made public as part of this.
- Shared assembly - contains interfaces (service contracts)

Question is - what's the best way to expose one of the contracts on the windows service via IIS, so all requests made to that publicly available service would be directly routed to backend windows service.

My first question of stackoverflow, if anything is unclear, i'll try to explain it further.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you are using IIS 7 then you can host the wcf service in IIS and expose one service contract with a HTTP binding, and the other non-public one as TCP-IP.

If you MUST host the server app as a windows service, then create a new IIS hosted service that has the same interface as the service contract you want public, but simply passes the calls through.

Comment: There's a plan to separate service app and web app to different machines in the (near) future, having service run alone without iis available there. This approach would work till then, but it'd be perfect to nail the final solution from the get-go.

Comment: That's why I offered option 2:)

Comment: You just added 2nd paragraph, and i think that's the thing i'm after. Could you elaborate a bit on "pass through" part? I'm hoping to avoid writing implementation of all methods just to invoke the "real" service. Is there a way for automated pass through?

Comment: I have not edited my post - 2nd paragraph was there from the start - If by implement the methods you mean pass through the call to the "real" service, no there is no way to avoid this. Hardly onerous though.

Comment: Not hard to do, just adds maintenance overhead when/if service changes. I'll wait a bit for other answers, before accepting yours. Thanks